# Ctrl-f does not scroll forward in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim

In MacVim 8.0, ctrl-f brings up a search window instead of scrolling forward in a buffer by one full screen. ctrl-F (i.e. pressing the SHIFT key also) gives the same result.

Is there a troubleshooting step or a repair step I can take?

Comment: Are you confusing `Ctrl-` with `Cmd-`?

Comment: No; both Ctrl-f and Cmd-f give the same results (a search window pops up).

Comment: `:verbose map <C-f>`

Comment: Thanks; mswin.vim has the mapping; how do I disable that bit (is that a separate question for SO?)

Comment: MacVim doesn't source that script by itself. It *must* be sourced somewhere in your config.

Comment: My macvim vimrc sources the script, which remaps ctrl-f. On windows gvim 7.4, which also sources mswin, ctrl-f is not remapped.

Comment: `mswin.vim` is only sourced in one place: `$VIMRUNTIME/evim.vim`, which itself is only ever sourced when you start Vim as `$ evim` or as `$ vim -y`.

Comment: @romaini 's comment about `:verbose map <C-f> is helpful in finding where this mapping is coming from.

Comment: On Windows gvim version 8.2.1484,  ctrl-f is remapped to "find."  Thanks to [monojohnny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143511/ctrl-f-does-not-scroll-forward-in-macvim/53533136#comment118908445_53533136) for the suggestion to simply :unmap it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about the MacVim. But I had experienced same situation at window gvim.

I mean when I press "Ctrl+F" I don't want to see search window.

I found the below at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim81\mswin.vim".

To resolve your problem, all you have to do is just comment the below line, that's it.

```
if has("gui")
  " CTRL-F is the search dialog
  noremap  <expr> <C-F> has("gui_running") ? ":promptfind\<CR>" : "/"
  inoremap <expr> <C-F> has("gui_running") ? "\<C-\>\<C-O>:promptfind\<CR>" : "\<C-\>\<C-O>/"
  cnoremap <expr> <C-F> has("gui_running") ? "\<C-\>\<C-C>:promptfind\<CR>" : "\<C-\>\<C-O>/"

  " CTRL-H is the replace dialog,
  " but in console, it might be backspace, so don't map it there
  nnoremap <expr> <C-H> has("gui_running") ? ":promptrepl\<CR>" : "\<C-H>"
  inoremap <expr> <C-H> has("gui_running") ? "\<C-\>\<C-O>:promptrepl\<CR>" : "\<C-H>"
  cnoremap <expr> <C-H> has("gui_running") ? "\<C-\>\<C-C>:promptrepl\<CR>" : "\<C-H>"
endif
```

Comment: Instead of editing the OOTB .vim file.Try using "unmap <C-F>" in your personal vim startup file.

Comment: I had to use the following to get commandline vim to not complain about C-F not being mapped:
`if has("gui")
  unmap <C-F>
endif`

Answer (score 2):

I think what happened is that gvim 8.0 has a mapping for `<Ctrl-f>` in mswin.vim, but the previous version of gvim does not have that mapping in mswin.vim

I use both versions (on different computers), and so got surprised by the `<Ctrl-f>` mapping in the gvim 8.0 version.

My vimrc sources mswin.vim because I like the copy-paste functionality.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Vscode, change `"<C-f>"` from `false` to `true`.

[image: ligne 81]